# Data Source to Excel Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, date-time, google-spreadsheets

I've been trying to import data from excel to google sheet. The data I got was in the format of dd/mm/yyyy, which makes sense as we use it in where I live; however, once I tried to copy paste the data in google sheet, it was the same exact date, except the format become mm/dd/yyyy instead.

E.g.
Excel --> 08/12/2021 (DD/MM/YYYY)
Google Sheet --> 08/12/2021 (MM/DD/YYYY)
When I tried to use the month function, it completely reversed, showing date instead of month, or even when I use the week function (it took the reverse one as well.

I've been trying to look for a way to fix this, but haven't been able to. I tried converting it to text value, but it doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean when you write "trying to import data from excel to google sheet"? Have you saved your Excel workbook to Google Drive and opened it in Google Sheets? Not? And why?

Comment: Did you copy and paste or other ways to import Excel Worksheet to Google Sheet?

Comment: I copy paste into my google sheet. What I'm working on is a dashboard, which shows the company's weekly performance (Week 1,Week 2, etc), and so on. I'm planning on update it weekly, so it would be a hassle to import the excel file into it every week and having to share it to the others every week. So I'm planning on using raw data, and provide insights into the data to the viewers.

Comment: In sheets, **before** you paste, navigate to `File => Settings => Locale` and change it to a locale (like your own) that uses the DMY format.  Or in Excel, before you copy, change the format of the cells to DMY.